# how I get the html source with utf-8 format?

Tags: android, post, android-webview

I write this code to get html source from a site.

```
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        OutputStreamWriter request = null;

        URL url = null;
        String response = null;
        String parameters = "aranan="+et.getText();

        try
        {
            url = new URL("http://www.fragmanfan.com/arama.asp");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            request.write(parameters);
            request.flush();
            String line = "";
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            // Response from server after login process will be stored in response variable.
            response = sb.toString();
            // You can perform UI operations here
            browser.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, response,"text/html", "UTF-8", null);

            isr.close();
            reader.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            // Error
        }
    }
});
```

But there is a one problem.It is : response (the variable that have html source) is not utf-8 format.
How I can fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "utf-8");

Answer (score 0):

.
.
.

```
 InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),"ISO-8859-9");
```

.
.
.

Answer (score -1):

Since your response seems to be your HTML webpage in a single String, you should make sure that the head tag of your page cointains the label that defines the codification.. if not you can append it yourself to your StringBuilder.
Here is how you can do it:

```
final StringBuilder sb = 
new StringBuilder("<html><head>"+ "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\"content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\" />"+ "</head><body>");
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
response = sb.toString();
sb.append(response);
sb.append("</body></html>");
```

and then you can properly load your HTML to your webview / browser. (this worked for me so I know for sure that it actually works =] )

p.d. make sure to accept the answer that properly answer your question so people keep answering your future questions.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: it doesnot work because the problem is that:line is not utf-8 format

Comment: I mean  sb.append(line + "\n");  this line return for example like this hal? (it can be halı) . you write first <meta....> but it does not efect

Comment: I mean reader.readline return back not utf-8 chars.How I can fix it